# Changing the size of a view in OnLayoutChangeListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I've implemented a gallery using the recyclerview and I've added an onLayoutChangeListener to the viewholder so that once the layout is calculated, the height of the imageview is changed to match the image's aspect ratio. It works fine when first opening the activity, rotating the device or unlocking the screen, but when coming back from another activity it doesn't work. The method is executed, but the imageview does not change. Any idea of what could be causing this?

```
        image.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
                Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                img.getLayoutParams().height = Utils.scaledHeight(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), img.getWidth());
                img.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }
        });
```

The debugger shows the correct height being set, but the displayed imageview is not what it should be.

[Correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Y0H.png)

[Incorrect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RURnX.png)

Comment: it may has something to do where You set it onCreate(). If You are rotating Your phone, the layout os getting destroyed and build again, like if You are opening the app the first time. But coming back from another app, only calls onResume()......maybe here is the problem....

Comment: How is the width being determined?  You might be able to solve this with `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on the ImageView.

Comment: @krislarson Thanks, that solved the issue. I didn't know that option existed. Instead of using the listener I just use that option and now it always works.

Comment: Great! I put that into an answer so you can mark as correct.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're just trying to get the proper aspect ratio on an `ImageView`.

`ImageView` has a property called `adjustViewBounds`.  If you have a specific layout_width like `match_parent` or a `dp` value, you can specify `wrap_content` for the layout_height and set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.  This will cause the `ImageView` to automatically respect the aspect ratio of the image when measuring for the height.